# How to edit Laravel migration table in database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I need to remove a single value from a laravels migration table, but within the database (I use phpmyadmin) I cant edit any data on the table i can click on the table but nothing more theres not even an option to delete the separate fields, does anyone know why this is and furthermore how would i alter the tables.

[image]

To prevent any further confusion its the table thats auto generated by laravel and auto updated anytime you run any migrations

Comment: your value in context means column name right 
?

Comment: @VforVendetta Yeah like the column itself or rows, not sure exactly what to call it

Comment: you means data of that table or structure ? if structure you can do through migration, but if you want to remove data then not possible, you can use phpmyadmin to remove data of that table

Comment: @VforVendetta Yes remove the data I just need to remove 1 field from the migrations but I physically cant edit the data in any of the fields like i can with the other tbales

Comment: we use alter table for dropping,modifying,adding columns of the table, and insert, update table for manipulation of records inside the table. So you want to alter right ?

Comment: If yes,create modify_table_name migrations and write code as Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->dropColumn(['name_of_column']);
}); . It will work

Comment: @VforVendetta I think you guys are missing what im saying here, its the pre built table the actual "Migrations" table thats auto-generated with Laravel when you make a migration

Comment: If you're using L5.3 or higher you can do `php artisan migrate:rollback --step=1` to revert last migration (increase step for more). It's not answer to your question, but in some cases it can be very helpful.

Comment: @devk Thanks this will be helpful in future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

just copy paste migration value which is 2015_12_07..., something like that
and fire query in phpmyadmin as

```
delete from migrations where migration = 'copy_pasted_string'
```

I hope this will work

And yes, you can perform all operation on the record by this string.

Answer (score 6):

It's important to know why you're using migrations. The best benefit of migrations is that you can redeploy an application and the database will have the same structure. This means that if I make a migration, and you deploy my application and run the migration, we both have the same database.

This means when you're using the migrations you have to keep that in mind. When you make a migration you change the database. If you want to change something after that, you'll have to make another migration. If you change the existing migration files or change your database manually the database won't be the same. This means different errors in different environments and alot of other problems you'll face.

So to answer your question, make the changes to your database using another migration.

Some links that can be of help to you understanding this concept:

- [Why use migrations](http://laravel.io/forum/02-23-2015-why-use-migration)
- [Migrations documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations)

Comment: I misunderstood your question. I know what you mean now. You can't edit a table that has no primary keys in phpmyadmin. What you can do is use SQL statements. You can run a `DELETE FROM migrations
WHERE batch=2;` statement to delete all migrations with batch 2. I don't know what you would want to change in this table though, but using SQL statements will make it possible.

Comment: This isnt the answer to the questing i posted but its solved the problem that led to this you gave me a better understanding of the migrations!

Comment: Yeah I misunderstood the question, but I'm happy to help haha. It can be a bit hard to grasp the purpose of migrations, but if you manage to understand them, they will make your life a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#dropping-columns

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->dropColumn('votes');
});
```